# Use new created plugin on another machine

Tags: java, nlp, gate

I am new to GATE-NLP . I have created my own Plugin.It is working fine . But now I want to use it in another machine . I dont want to copy the folder from my machine to anothers plugin folder . How can i do that ?

Comment: The plugin code has to available on the another machine. What kind of transfer (other than folder copy) would you prefer?

Comment: See also the GATE user guide / chapter 12.3.5 **Distributing Your New Plugins**: https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:development:disributingplugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the application distribution between machines I usually create a folder which contains all necessary plugins for application. All resources could be loaded from this folder. With this approach application has no dependencies from GATE framework installation.

Comment: I think you can use the "Export for GATECloud.net" option for this purpose. See https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:family:cloud-preparing-app

Comment: Sometimes it's not possible due to the requirements. With the approach described above it's possible to deliver .war file for web app ( or jar + plugins folder) as a single file.